# Kotlin's identityEquals not working as expected

Tags: kotlin

According to kotlin [reference](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#representation), this code snippet should prints "true"

```
val a: Int = 10000
print(a identityEquals a)
```

But when I try it (version is 0.12.1218), it prints "false". Why?

**2015/07/29 UPDATE**

If let a in [-128 ~ 127], it prints "true". As Andrey said, should use `===`.

Comment: Confirmed on v0.12.213.  However, a === a returns true as expected.  It seems that the identityEquals(Any?, Any?) function is (incorrectly?) being called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`identityEquals` will be deprecated soon, use `===`

Answer (score 5):

I found the [explain](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-3774) from Andrey Breslav.

> The reason is that under the hoods Int is not a reference type: it's represented by a primitive int, but when you are calling identityEquals, who signature is Any?.identityEquals(Any?), it both operands get boxed, and as a result we have two different objects. We'll fix this by introducing overloads of identityEquals for Java primitives.

Until now it still haven't be fixed. The official reference should explain this. It has troubled me for several hours.